# What is the right way to run parameterized queries for flex tables with odbc driver?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm pretty much new to Vertica and its flex tables concept. Need to insert data into the flex table with help of odbcParameter like that

```
string query = "INSERT INTO flexTable SELECT MapJSONExtractor(@flexDataToInsert) as event"
var connection = GetConnection(); // returns OdbcConnection
var command = GetCommand(connection, queryString.ToString()); // returns OdbcCommand
OdbcParameter param = command.Parameters.Add("@flexDataToInsert", OdbcType.NText, 2048);
param.Value = data; // long json to insert
await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
```

but get the exception "OdbcException: ERROR [42703] ERROR 2624:  Column "flexDataToInsert" does not exist". After struggling for hours still can't realize what's wrong with it

Comment: ODBC doesn't allow named parameters except for stored procedures. Use positional parameters (eg `INSERT INTO flexTable SELECT MapJSONExtractor(?) as event`) and define the parameters in the order they are used in the query

Comment: I tried that too, but then I got "ERROR [42601] ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near ")" at character 55"